# CCNetConfig command line parameter for opening a ccnet.config?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

I'm trying out [CCNetConfig](http://ccnetconfig.codeplex.com/)  (warning, website a little slow).  Great app, one annoyance.

I can see in the documentation and even in the [source code](http://ccnetconfig.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/46726#405981) (Look at the end of the Initialize method) that I should be able to pass in a command line parameter to automatically load the configuration file.

I have tried:

```
-f E:\CruiseControl.Net\server\ccnet.config
-file E:\CruiseControl.Net\server\ccnet.config
-f=E:\CruiseControl.Net\server\ccnet.config
-file=E:\CruiseControl.Net\server\ccnet.config
```

And the same 4 switches with quotes around the file name just in case.

They all produce errors or just don't work.  Has anyone had success doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving it to a different path. Try the simplest thing: c:\ccnet.config.

I'm guessing it's the source of the problem because I recall CCNetConfig gave me sh!t early on when I tried to open files in paths that had spaces in them (e..g in Program Files).

Answer (score 0):

According to my version of CCNet the command line flag for using a different config file is -c or --config, so the following should do it...

```
-c "E:\CruiseControl.Net\server\ccnet.config"
```

...which works for me.

I don't know why it uses a non-standard flag, but there you go.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. He is talking about the helper program called `CCNetConfig`. **Not** the server program called `ccnet`.